# Twitter Bootstrap nuget package differences?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012

I want to bootstrap my MVC 4 application but am not sure which ones I want or need. The descriptions are pretty vague and I'm having trouble finding a nice breakdown of what each of these versions mean.

[image]

**What are the main differences/similarities and which one should I choose?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Twitter.Boostrap is currently just a dependency link to "Bootstrap", the first option.  So I take that as Bootstrap is all you need.  If you install Twitter.Bootstrap, a readme.txt will be opened.

**From the Twitter.Bootstrap nuget package readme.txt:**

> Twitter.Bootstrap is moving!
>
> v3.0.1 will be the last release of Bootstrap under the Twitter.Bootstrap namespace. With new projects moving forward, you should install Bootstrap directly from the Bootstrap namespace maintained by Outercurve https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap/
>   For existing projects, you already have the new Bootstrap package installed by upgrading to this release.

Answer (score 2):

I have been wondering about the same thing, it is really confusing with all these different versions and in my opinion it highlights kind of a big problem with NuGet. Maybe they could introduce a "Supported"/"Verified" badge or something?

Anyways - the first package has Outercurve as its owner and doesn't come with the Twitter namespace. As Outercurve was funded by Microsoft and only started offering the package as of May 2012 (oddly version 1.0.0, even though Bootstrap had reached at least 2.0.3 by then), I would imagine that this is the "official" MS-version of Bootstrap that now comes included as the default template in Visual Studio.

It is worth noting that even though NuGet wants you to update to the latest version 3, the VS 2013RC project templates still come with version 2 markup, and the samples will (at least visually) break if updated.

Answer (score 0):

The first one will install .css, .js and .img files and jquery too. Bootstrap for MVC 4 installs Bootstrap and supports bundling and minification.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on an MVC 4 web app that had jQuery 1.8.2. The Nuget package manager seemed to handle all the dependencies when I installed Bootstrap 3.3.1. **However, it only upgraded my app to jQuery 1.9.0 instead of the jQuery 1.9.1 that it required.** ***So I would say that if you just install the version that shows up at the top of the list like I did (Bootstrap 3.3.1), you need to end up with jQuery 1.9.1 or higher.*** My solution was to run "Install-Package jQuery -Version 1.9.1" in the Package Manager Console of Visual Studio. I was using Visual Studio 2013. *By the way, in the Manage Nuget Packages window of Visual Studio, the information for Bootstrap 3.3.1 said "Dependencies: jQuery (>= 1.9.0)!*